# If $f$ is smooth and bijective, is $f^{-1}$ smooth, too?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be open. Assume that the function $f \colon U \rightarrow f(U)$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ and a bijection and its differential $\text{d}f(x)$ is injective for every $x \in U$. Furthermore, assume that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Is this enough to conclude that also $f^{-1}$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$?

I tried to use the inverse function theorem, but this only gives me a locally result and no inverse function $f^{-1}$ with maximal domain $f(U)$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f^{-1}=:g$. The inverse function theorem contains the formula
$$dg=\iota\circ df\circ g\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $\iota$ denotes taking the inverse of a regular linear map $L:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n$. As $f$ and $\iota$ are $C^\infty$ formula $(1)$ can be used to set up an induction proof that $g$ is $C^\infty$ as well, starting from $g\in C^0$ (which should be included in the proof of the inverse function theorem), and making heavy use of the chain rule.

Comment: The problem I have with the IFT is that it tells me that for each $x \in U$ there is $U_0$ open such that $x \in U_0 \subset U$ and $V$ open such that $f(x) \in V$ and $f \colon U_0 \rightarrow V$ is a diffeomorphism. But how can I be sure that $V = f(U)$, i.e. the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is a map defined on $f(U)$?

Comment: For each point $y\in f(U)$ you can find at least one point $x\in U$ with $f(x)=y$. The IFT then guarantees that each such $x$ has a neighborhood $U'$ which is mapped diffeomorphically onto a neighborhood $V'$ of $y$. Take $\exp:\>{\mathbb C}\to{\mathbb C}$ as an example: Each $w\in\exp({\mathbb C})=\dot{\mathbb C}$ has infinitely many preimages $z\in{\mathbb C}$, and each such $z$ has a neighborhood which is mapped difeomorphically onto a neighborhood of the given $w$.

Comment: So for each $y = f(x)$ I get a locally diffeomorphism from $U'(x)$ onto $V'(y)$. But since $\bigcup_{x \in U} U'(x) = U$ and $\bigcup_{y \in f(U)} V'(y) = f(U)$ I can put them toegether to a diffeomorphism from $U$ onto $f(U)$. Is this correct?